# how to return a reference of an object from std::vector<std::vector<>>

Tags: c++, reference, stdvector

like in the title, here is a pice of code:

```
class matrix{
    std::vector<std::vector<bool>> base;
    std::pair<int, int> size;
public:
    matrix(int x, int y){
        size.first = x; size.second = y;
        std::vector<std::vector<bool>> b(x, std::vector<bool>(y));
        base = b;
    }
    bool& operator ()(int x, int y) const {
        if(x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= size.first || y >= size.second){outOfBounds ex; throw ex;}
        return base[x][y];
    }
    /*and more that is unrelated to the question*/
};
```

the error is in `bool& operator(...)` and it is as follows:

```
cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘bool&’ to an rvalue of type‘std::vector<bool>::const_reference’ {aka ‘bool’}
   30 |                 return base[x][y];
```

in the code, the size of the vector (matrix) **dose not change**

I also replaced bool with int and its the same problem, can't convert from `int` to `int&`

The function can't be const, so that the value of the reference can be changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool& operator ()(int x, int y) const {
```

The `const` at the end means that this is a ***constant*** class method, and ***this*** is constant.

```
return base[x][y];
```

Everything in ***this*** is constant. Including this. The return value from this operator overload should, therefore, be `const bool &` instead of `bool &`.

If after understanding this you go back and reread your compiler's error message it should now make perfect sense to you, because that's exactly what your compiler was telling you.

Alternatively you can drop the `const` from the overloaded operator declaration, and return a `bool &`, that's up to you.

But then, you're going to wind up with another, special problem: a `std::vector<bool>` is not really a vector of bools, but [something very weird](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool).

So, the final solution may be to simply declare the return value as an `auto &`, and let the compiler figure it out for you. ...You don't really want to know what it really is.

Comment: after dropping the `const` from the function declaration the message is as follows:

```
error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘bool&’ to an rvalue of type ‘bool’
   30 |                 return base[x][y];

```

Comment: Yes, that's another problem, `std::vector<bool>` is not really a vector of `bool`s. Updated my answer to suggest declaring the return value as an `auto &`.